# Can an object of a subclass access protected field of another object of another subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, protected

I learnt the following from the book Core Java, Volume I--Fundamentals (8th Edition) > Chapter 5: Inheritance > 'Protected Access' section (Page 205).

> There are times, however, when you want to restrict a method to
>   subclasses only or, less commonly, to allow subclass methods to access
>   a superclass field. In that case, you declare a class feature as
>   protected. For example, if the superclass Employee declares the
>   hireDay field as protected instead of private, then the Manager
>   methods can access it directly.
>
> However, **the Manager class methods can peek inside the hireDay field
>   of Manager objects only, not of other Employee objects.** This
>   restriction is made so that you can’t abuse the protected mechanism
>   and form subclasses just to gain access to the protected fields.

I wrote the following code to test it.

```
class Employee
{
    protected String name;

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Manager extends Employee
{
    public Manager(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void peekName(Employee e) {
        System.out.println("name: " + e.name);
    }
}

class Executive extends Employee
{
    public Executive(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}

public class TestProtectedAccess
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee e = new Employee("Alice Employee");
        Manager m = new Manager("Bob Manager");
        Executive ex = new Executive("Charles Executive");

        // Manager object accessing protected name of Employee object
        m.peekName(e);

        // Manager object accessing protected name of Executive object
        m.peekName(ex);
    }
}
```

The output of the code is:

```
$ java TestProtectedAccess
name: Alice Employee
name: Charles Executive
```

The Manager object `m` is able to access protected field `name` of other Employee objects `e` and `ex`. This seems to contradict what I have quoted above from the book, especially the part that I have highlighted in bold.

Can someone explain me if the book is wrong or is my understanding wrong? If my understanding is wrong can you suggest a better example to understand what the book means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your classes are all in the same package , protected is the same as public.

> The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed
>   within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by
>   a subclass of its class in another package.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: Yes You can definitely do it.